# words stemmer class c#

Tags: c#

I am trying the following stemming class :

```
static class StemmerSteps
{
    public static string stepSufixremover(this string str, string suffex)
    {
        if (str.EndsWith(suffex))
        {
            ................
        }
        return str;
    } 

    public static string stepPrefixemover(this string str, string prefix)
    {
        if (str.StartsWith(prefix) 
        {
            .....................
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

this class works with one prefix or suffix. is there any suggestion to allow a list of prefixes or suffixes to go through the class and compare against each (str). your kind action really appreciated.

Comment: Question quality suggestion - consider editing this question. Please follow C# coding guidelines for public sample code. I.e. classes should be upper case, methods should have first letter of each word capitalized like `StepOne`. Avoid intentional misspelling like `suffex`.

Comment: and make class `static`, cause you're implementing extension methods.

Comment: and don't name the methods `stepone/steptwo` but `RemoveSuffix/RemovePrefix`.

Comment: @Jone Mamni: what if I have a case like `"hello".stepSufixremover(new string[]{"o","l"})` ? What is expected output here?

Comment: I'm not working with english language

Comment: @JoneMamni: You haven't answered Tigrans question. Do you just want to look if the string starts-/endswith any of the passed strings or do you want to look again after you've removed one?

Comment: yes i just want to look if the string starts-/endswith any of the passed strings. i don't to look again.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating your own class from scratch (unless this is homework) I would definitive use an existing library. This answer provides an example of code that that implements the Porter Stemming Algorithm:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611455/how-to-perform-stemming-in-c

Comment: Which existing library?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Considering your comment:

"just want to look if the string starts-/endswith **any** of the passed strings"

may be something like this can fit your needs:

```
public static string stepSufixremover(this string str, IEnumerable<string> suffex)
{           
   string suf = suffex.Where(x=>str.EndsWith(x)).SingleOrDefault();
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(suf))
   {            
    str = str.Remove(str.Length - suf.Length, suf.Length);
   }
   return str;
}
```

If you use this like:

```
"hello".stepone(new string[]{"lo","l"}).Dump();
```

it produces:

```
hel
```

Comment: could you post a simple example please?

Answer (score 0):

Put your suffix/prefixes in a collection (like a `List<>`), and loop through and apply each possible one.  This collection would need to be passed into the method.

```
List<string> suffixes = ...;
for (suffix in suffixes)
    if (str.EndsWith(suffix))
        str = str.Remove(str.Length - suffix.Length, suffix.Length);
```

Comment: Assuming that multiple prefixes and suffixes could exist -- you'll need to restart your loop every time a prefix/suffix is found (since we have no knowledge of what order in which the prefixes/suffixes may exist)

Comment: By @mellamokb: correctly remove the suffix 'ing' from 'singing'?

Comment: maybe i should try regex. something like "^sufeixes"

Comment: @ean5533: OP has responded with a comment on the question that only one suffix/prefix will ever be removed, not multiple: "yes i just want to look if the string starts-/endswith any of the passed strings. i don't to look again."

Answer (score 0):

The simplest code would involve regular expressions.

For example, this would identify some English suffixes:

```
'^(.*?)(ing|ly|ed|ious|ies|ive|es|s|ment)?$'
```

One problem is that stemming is not as accurate as lemmatization. Lematization would require POS tagging for accuracy. For example, you don't want to add an *-ing* suffix to *dove* if it's a noun.

Another problem is that some suffixes also require prefixes. For example, you must add *en-* to *-rich-* to add a *-ment* suffix in *en-rich-ment* -- unlike a root like *-govern-* where you can add the suffix without any prefix.